# Maven won't deploy to Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy a Java rest server to tomcat, using Maven tomcat plugin, but Tomcat isn't working properly.

When deploying (through either *-e tomcat7:deploy* or *-e tomcat7:redeploy*), Tomcat replies with:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building com.testTomcat Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) > package @ com.testTomcat >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ com.testTomcat ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\and_s\TestTomcat\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ com.testTomcat ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:testResources (default-testResources) @ com.testTomcat ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\and_s\TestTomcat\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ com.testTomcat ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ com.testTomcat ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.2.2:war (default-war) @ com.testTomcat ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [com.testTomcat] in [C:\Users\and_s\TestTomcat\target\com.testTomcat]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\and_s\TestTomcat\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [122 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\and_s\TestTomcat\target\com.testTomcat.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) < package @ com.testTomcat <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) @ com.testTomcat ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/webapp  
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fwebapp&update=true

[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fwebapp&update=true

[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fwebapp&update=true

[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fwebapp&update=true

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.802 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-26T16:41:02+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/311M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project com.testTomcat: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection reset by peer: socket write error -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project com.testTomcat: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:181)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager$RequestEntityImplementation.writeTo(TomcatManager.java:880)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:203)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:682)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:742)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:705)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:132)
    ... 24 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have checked that tomcat is running. None of the fixes I found on previous Stack overflow worked.

This is my pom configuration for the tomcat plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>tomcatserver</server>
        <path>/webapp</path>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <update>true</update>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is my maven .settings:

```
<server>
    <id>tomcatserver</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>password</password>
</server>
```

And this is the web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.testtomcat</param-value>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

What could be wrong in my configuration?

**EDIT**: Here is part of the output when using -X argument: https://pastebin.com/GAqUMDFp

**EDIT 2**: Here is the tomcat-users.xml:

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager"/>
    <role rolename="admin"/>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <user username="admin" password="password" roles="admin,manager,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging -> This will give you better idea.

Comment: From what I gather, Tomcat is closing the connection, why would that be?

Comment: Is the admin user set up with the appropriate manager roles in your tomcat-users.xml?

Comment: I would think so, I added on the 2nd edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very sorry for my stupidity. Apparently it was due to lack of Administrator rights. I can't believe I missed that.

Apparently running the server as admin helps (I put the tomcat folder in the *Program Files* and apparently Windows doesn't like that).